# Difficulty passing in a html element from a nodelist to an anonymous functionult

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am attempting to add an eventListener to each html element from a nodelist, and pass that same html element as an argument to the callback function. My code looks like so.

```
let programs = document.getElementsByClassName('program-name')
for (i = 0; i < programs.length; i++){
    programs[i].addEventListener("click", () => testFunc(programs[i]))
}
function testFunc(program) {
    console.log(program)
}
```

The problem is that I am expecting `console.log(program)` to log an html element to the console, however all the log is `undefined`

Comment: your html please?

Comment: `programs[i]` is undefined because `i` is out-of-bounds. The reason is that you are using a global variable for `i` that will, by the time `testFunc` is called for the first time, already equal `programs.length` (after the loop) which is out of bounds. Check out the suggested duplicate

Comment: 2 possible solutions.

1 ) use `for (let i = 0; i < programs.length;i ++)` it will keep a local copy of `i` in each round of the loop.

2) use the event object, and grab the   event.s currentTarget  `programs[i].addEventListenr("click", (event) => testFunc(event.currentTarget)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using closure (as suggested in the comments), you can make use of `event` object passed to the handler as such:

```
programs[i].addEventListener("click", (evt) => testFunc(evt.currentTarget))
```

Then, the HTML element that was clicked will be passed to the callback.